# React Redux: How to find last action called in Redux and fire that same action again

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have multiple places where different actions are executed when clicked.

I would like to find that very latest action that was executed and then execute it again just using a "Renew" button.

How do I look for this last action called?
It must be in the redux system somewhere.  I just need to know how to find it.

Comment: I think you need to manually maintain last action called in state.

Comment: Did you mean redux devtools or do you intend to fire up last action programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I look for this last action called? It must be in the redux system somewhere.

I'm not aware of any place redux saves past actions. But you could create a [custom middleware](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware) to intercept and save the action. Something like:

```
let lastAction = null;
export const getLastAction = () => lastAction;

export const lastActionMiddleware = store => next => action => {
 lastAction = action;
 return next(action);
}

// In another file, initialize your store with the middleware
// Your code may look different here if you already have middlewares:

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { lastActionMiddleware } from 'whatever/the/path/is';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  rootState, 
  applyMiddleware(lastActionMIddleware)
)

// And in yet another file, you can look up the most recent action

import { getLastAction } from 'whatever/the/path/is';

// ...

componentDidMount() {
  const lastAction = getLastAction();
  console.log('the last thing dispatched anywhere was:', lastAction)
}
```